# There is already an object named 'vedere1' in the database

Tags: mysql, sql, management-studio-express

this is my code:

--Vedere care conține clienții ce au inchiriat camere:

```
USE Sunset

GO

CREATE VIEW  vedere1 AS

SELECT DISTINCT c.Nume AS num_client, r.Nr_camera AS camera, f.Data_emiterii, f.Suma

FROM factura f, clienti c, camera r

WHERE (f.Id_client=c.Id_client) AND (r.Id_client=c.Id_client)

GO
```

and this is my error: There is already an object named 'vedere1' in the database

what should I do?

Comment: Please use appropriate tags, this cannot be about both `mysql` and `management studio express`

Comment: Give the view a name that isn't already taken?

Comment: Have you read the error text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says, you are trying to create a `view` with a name that already exists in your database.

If you want to modify/change it, use `alter` instead of `create`.

If you want to create new view, change the name of the view.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, that object may already exist.
does 
    select * from vedere1

return anything?

If so use the following script if you REALLY want to overwrite the existing View.
    --Vedere care conține clienții ce au inchiriat camere:

```
USE Sunset

GO

ALTER VIEW vedere1 AS

SELECT DISTINCT c.Nume AS num_client, r.Nr_camera AS camera, 
f.Data_emiterii, f.Suma

FROM factura f, clienti c, camera r

WHERE (f.Id_client=c.Id_client) AND (r.Id_client=c.Id_client)

GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Just double check there is not also a table with this name- this was my issue when the same error appeared.

Answer (score 0):

You have already have a  **vedere1** view.